# Load links as unselected in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have sets of links with id and name attributes, id for individual identifiers and names for groupings.  In my jQuery, I have a click function that manipulates the CSS based on what a user clicks on.

But I want to start the freshly loaded page with some of the links disabled (no href attribute) and with a style applied.  I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
$(function() // Alias for $(document).ready()
{ 
var $links = $('li a');   

     $links.(function(){
                $('a[name="beam"]').filter(function() {
                    $(this).addClass('unavailable');
                    $(this).removeAttr('href');
                });

            }); ......
```

Ideas?  (Beam is one of the groupings by name).

Comment: what is the `$links.(...)` part supposed to do ? Seems like syntax error.

Comment: See my new edit.  I want to write something that happens on page load.

Comment: OK, fine but how do I fix it.  That's what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.each` (or `.map`) instead of `.filter`:

```
$('li a[name="beam"]').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('unavailable');
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) works fine (*if you use it correctly*)

```
var $links = $('li a');   

 $links
     .filter('[name="beam"]')
     .addClass('unavailable')
     .removeAttr('href');
```

**demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/LhVv6/